# javascript insert new row same as first row when press enter in html table last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert new row in html table when user press enter on keyboard.  At beginning I already added first tr when create the table. In this tr, first td contain html dropdown list($select_chooseitem) that contain data from database.Second column is textbox. I want to use javascript to get first tr element set and create new row based on that. tr element set would be like:

```
<tr>
 <td>first col</td>
 <td>second col</td>
</tr>
```

I do not want to declare new tr element set. But, want to retrieve first tr element set from table. Is this possible?

```
$row_html           ='<tr>
                            <td>'.$select_chooseitem.'</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="order"></td>
                    </tr>';

$html_complete='<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                        <head>
                            <script>
                                $(function () {
                                    // Change the selector if needed
                                    var $table = $(".mt-table-edit");

                                    //addNewRow();


                                    function addNewRow() {    
                                        //get row template. We must use html() for new instance other event handler will get attached to last row
                                       //var $tr = $("<tr><td><input/></td><td><input/></td><td><input/></td><td><input/></td></tr>");        
                                         var $tr = $("<tr><td><input/></td><td><input/></td></tr>");        

                                        $tr.find("td").eq($tr.find("td").length - 1).keyup(function (e) {
                                            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                                                addNewRow();
                                            }
                                        });

                                        // add template after the last row
                                        $table.find("tbody:last-child").append($tr);       

                                        // focus on firt input of newly added row
                                        $tr.find("td:first input").focus();
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>               
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <table  class="mt-table-edit">
                                '.$row_html.'
                            </table>


                        </body>

                    </html>';
                    echo $html_complete;
//echo $query_tbltemplateitems;
```

Since first one not work, other method I tried was getting $select_chooseitem in javascript to create tr element set. I tried access php variable($select_chooseitem) in js by `addNewRow('.$select_chooseitem.');` ,but not working. How is proper way to access php variable value from js?

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var $table = $(".mt-table-edit");
            var $row = $(".mt-table-edit").children("tr:first");
            addNewRow('.$select_chooseitem.');

            function addNewRow(var) 
            {    
              //get row template. We must use html() for new instance other event handler will get attached to last row
              //var $tr = $("<tr><td><input/></td><td><input/></td><td><input/></td><td><input/></td></tr>");        
               var $tr = $("<tr><td>var</td><td><input/></td></tr>");        
               $tr.find("td").eq($tr.find("td").length - 1).keyup(function (e) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) 
                {
                  addNewRow(var);
                }
               });
            $table.find("tbody:last-child").append($tr);       
            $tr.find("td:first input").focus();
            }

        });
    </script>
```

I have tried declare variable in js and try to access in js in head of html. not successful too.
Example:

```
<?php
 $select_chooseitem='<select>'.$option_list.'</select>';
?>
 <script>
  var select_chooseitem=<?php echo $select_chooseitem;?>;
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var` is a reserved word (`function addNewRow(var)`). Find the row you want to duplicate, call [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and insert that clone at the beginning of the table ([`.prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/))

Comment: Yes, var is reserved word.I did careless mistake. I have tried use `.clone()` and `.append()`. I can add new row but can do one time only. https://jsfiddle.net/premlathabalakrishnan/m5wc294h/3/

Comment: change `$table.find("tbody:last-child").append($tr);` to `$table.find("tr:eq(0)").clone().appendTo($table.find("tbody:last-child"));` can add row multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly try the code snippet below.

```js
$(document).on( 'keyup', '.name', function(){
  
  if (event.which == 13 && $(this).closest("tr").is(":last-child")) {
      var $tblbody = $('#mytable').find("tbody"),
      $tbltrlast = $tblbody.find("tr:last"),
      $trnew = $tbltrlast.clone();

      $tbltrlast.after($trnew);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='mytable'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='name' class='name' value='John Doe'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works for adding row by button click. Thank you. I want to try if possible to add row by enter. Now, I am able to add row by enter. But, I could not access the last tr of updated table row. I want to get last row to limit adding row function available for last row

Comment: @Premlatha - i have added a row limiter, please check.

Comment: kapitan, I checked. I do not want to limit number of rows. what I expecting is user can execute add row only by click enter on last row. Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/premlathabalakrishnan/m5wc294h/19/. My problem is , add row executed when user enter on any row.

Comment: @Premlatha - can you please try running the updated snippet?

Comment: Yes, it works as I expected! we need to use keyup `$(document).on( 'keyup', '.name', function(){` in this way to achieve this. Why `$(".mt-table-edit tr:last td:last").keyup(function(e) {` could not output result as above? Can you give explaination? Thank you.

Comment: @Premlatha - you can accept this as the answer if this solved your question for future reference of other that may encounter your problem. thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the first child of tr you can use this:

$('table tr:first-child')

Comment: yes, `$('table tr:first-child')` able to get first row from table.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using jQuery this code might be useful.

This code searches for a table tag then selects the first tr tag

```
$('table tr:first-child')
```

You can also achieve this using plain css

```
table tr:first-child{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: yes, `$('table tr:first-child')` able to get first row from table.

Answer (score 0):

The required markup for the row is constructed.

```
 markup = "<tr>
                        <td>'.$select_chooseitem.'</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="order"></td>
                </tr>"
```

The table body is selected to which the table rows to be added.

```
tableBody = $("table tbody")
```

Finally the markup is added to the table body.

```
tableBody.append(markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution Kaptian delivered seams like a good one, but he copys the last row of the Table. if you set newrow like that, it should do the job.

```js
    var newrow = $('#mytable tr:first-child').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestion and answers. By using  `.clone().appendTo()` and `keyup(function(e)`, I'm able to add new row by enter on keyboard. Every time enter, it did add new row after last tr. But ,could not limit add row will execute only when enter in last td of last row.

```js
$(function() {
  // Change the selector if needed
  var $table = $(".mt-table-edit");
  //var $row = $(".mt-table-edit").children("tr:first");
  addNewRow();

  function addNewRow() {
    var $tr = $table.find("tr:eq(0)").clone();
    //$(".mt-table-edit").keyup(function(e) { 
    //$(".mt-table-edit tr:last td:last").keyup(function(e) { 
    $($table.find("tbody:last-child")).keyup(function(e) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) //test enter key press on keyboard
      {
        //$table.find("tbody:last-child").append($tr); 
        $table.find("tr:eq(0)").clone().appendTo($table.find("tbody:last-child"));
      }
    });
    $tr.find("td:first input").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <table class="mt-table-edit" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>first col</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="order"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/premlathabalakrishnan/m5wc294h/19/)

Thanks in advance.